# unable to export html to pdf with jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I am trying to download my html file as pdf and i included this:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.js" ></script>
```

and this is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#content')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

and this is my html button :

```
 <div class="page-container container"><button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
       </div>
```

i am trying to export whatever it is in the 
into pdf - but my button actually does nothing. my console gives me this error :

```
parall.ax/products/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
parall.ax/products/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

i tried so many sample codes but none of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.text(30, 30, 'Hello world!');
    pdf.save('hello_world.pdf');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I downloaded  
techumber.com/2015/04/ code and i run it on localhost, this also does not work neither in chrome nor mozilla!

Comment: what is the reason?@ranjan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117804/discussion-between-user6485186-and-ranjan-satpathy).